# How do I reference a static resource inside a resource dictionary?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I reference a static resource from within a resource dictionary?  I want to reference colors in a converter's constructor.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="PrimaryLavendarDark">#000000</Color>
        <Color x:Key="PrimaryLavendarDarkAlpha50">#000000FF</Color>

        <converter:ColorChooserConverter x:Key="PrimaryPurpleDarkConverter">
            <x:Arguments>
                <Color>#000000</Color>
                <Color>#000000</Color>
            </x:Arguments>
        </converter:ColorChooserConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I want to be able to reference the Color PrimaryLavendarDark as an argument.

```
<Color>{StaticResource PrimaryLavendarDark}</Color>
```

The above code obviously doesn't work.  I also want to do this with XAML not in C# backend.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate of the question which @SushiHangover closed it with.